# Rails: Ajax/jQuery Issue with Pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a comment model that posts under a micropost both are paginated and both show on the same page.

I have done everything from http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax?view=asciicast and everything should work but the problem is that both micropost and commet are paginated and both are on the same page.

The links for both pagination turns into this `href="/users/2?page=2"` rather than `href="/users/2/micropost?page=2"` or `href="/users/2/comment?page=2"`. I am unsure how to go about solving this problem. Here are some of my code. All suggestions are much appreciated!

**Micropost Render HTML**

```
<table class="microposts">
<% if microposts.any? %>
<%= render microposts %>
<%= will_paginate microposts, :page_links => false %>
<% else %>
<div class="EmptyContainer"><span class='Empty'>Add a thread!</span></div>
<% end %>
</table>
```

**Comment Section HTML**

```
<div id='CommentContainer-<%= micropost.id%>' class='CommentContainer Condensed2'>
<div class='Comment'>
<%= render :partial => "comments/form", :locals => { :micropost => micropost } %>
</div>
<div id='comments'>
  <% comments = micropost.comments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) %>
  <%= render comments %>
  <%= will_paginate comments, :class =>"pagination" %>
</div>
</div>
```

**User Controller for the Show Page**

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = Micropost.new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comments = @micropost.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    @microposts = @user.microposts.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
     end
  end
```

Comment: i hope that fixed your issue = )

Answer (score 0):

to separate the two, you should go here

http://blog.devinterface.com/2011/08/tips-multiple-pagination-with-will_paginate/

you can pass in separate params, so that only one will paginate even if both are on the same page